# Terraform code to create gcp log based alerting policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcp-alerts

I am trying to create gcp log based alerting policy using terraform using the code given below :-

```
    resource "google_logging_metric" "my_log_metrics" {
  name = "my-log-metric"
  filter = filter     = "resource.type=\"service_account\" AND protoPayload.methodName=\"google.iam.admin.v1.DeleteServiceAccount\" AND resource.labels.email_id:\"vaultvault-\""
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "my_policy" {
  display_name = "my-policy"
  combiner = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "my-policy"
    condition_threshold {
      filter = "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/my-log-metric\" AND resource.type=\"service_account\""
    }
```

But getting the following error: Error creating AlertPolicy: googleapi: Error 400: Field alert_policy.conditions[0].condition_threshold.filter had an invalid value of "metric.type="logging.googleapis.com/user/my-metric" AND resource_type="service_account"": must specify a restriction on "resource.type" in the filter; see "https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources" for a list of available resource types.
│

Comment: Please share Terraform version and Google provider version?

Comment: Furthermore the first resource you pasted here looks syntactially wrong. Please update or remove